# Target Framework in Visual Studio has no effect?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-framework-version, .net-4.8

I'm wondering about the following behavior in Visual Studio 2015.
I have created a simple console application targeting .NET Framework 4.8 and display the target framework:

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.TargetFrameworkName`

The result is: `.NETFramework,Version=v4.5`

Why doesn't it return v4.8 instead v4.5?

**Edit**:
I now found this: The problem only occurs with the .vshost.exe. When running the .exe or disabling the vshost in Properties->Debugging, it correctly displays v4.8. I also found that the problem occurs with applications running in WcfSvcHost.

Comment: You need a clean build to force everything to recompile.  When you change Net versions there is no dependency to Net version force a recompile

Comment: Look in the app.config file, next look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246278/target-framework-set-as-net-4-6-2-but-targetframeworkname-shows-net-4-5)